# How to adjust Scroll speed on PyAutoGui Python Library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, mouse, pyautogui

I am using **PyAutoGui on python3.x**. And while using the Scroll function, the script scrolls very fast, its hard to see the movements at all. So, how can I slow down the scroll speed like we do using **moveTo** function!

```
import pyautogui as p
p.scroll(-20)
```

Thanks in Advance <3

Answer (score 2):

You have do a workaround. Using a `time.sleep`, you can give a pause between clicks.

```
import pyautogui as p
import time
for s in range(20):
    p.scroll(-1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```